# MYSQL Update Table set column equal to select column from same table

Tags: mysql

I have a new column in my database and I need fill it up with the value of the same column from one specific row. I want to create a feature "copy to all"

For example add the same price to all the products taken from the first row:

```
ID   NAME   PRICE
1    PROD1    5
2    PROD2    0
3    PROD3    0
4    PROD4    0
```

I am trying to select the PRICE of the first row (ID 1) and copy it to all the other rows.

I have tried:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS SET PRICE = (select PRICE from PRODUCTS where ID = 1);
```

I want to end up with this

```
ID   NAME   PRICE
1    PROD1    5
2    PROD2    5
3    PROD3    5
4    PROD4    5
```

But I get this error:

```
 Table 'PRODUCTS' is specified twice, 
 both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data
```

I tried specifying each table separately

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS as a SET a.PRICE = (select b.PRICE from PRODUCTS as b where b.ID = 1);
```

But I get the same error.

```
 Table 'a' is specified twice, 
 both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data
```

Maybe I have to create a temporary table and copy from it? 
Any hints on how to accomplish this?
Thanks.

Comment: I believe the cheap and nasty way is you put your select query inside another set of brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by nesting the select query:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS 
SET PRICE = (
  select PRICE from (select PRICE from PRODUCTS where ID = 1) t
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fGHPDqv6VuKMjy8zaw8oSp/0).
Another way to do it, with a self CROSS JOIN:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS p CROSS JOIN (
  select PRICE from PRODUCTS where ID = 1
) t 
SET p.PRICE = t.PRICE;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fGHPDqv6VuKMjy8zaw8oSp/1).

Comment: Nice! This worked too, what is t for? are you naming the select t? is it required?

Comment: MySql requires the subquery to be aliased.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work logically, as SQL would try to fetch the data it is updating.

Try running your nested statement `select PRICE from PRODUCTS where ID = 1` seperately, saving the response and then running your main statement: `"UPDATE PRODUCTS SET PRICE = " + newPrice`

Answer (score 0):

After looking at many answers on other posts and websites, (none of them had the precise answer), I found the solution with this query, and yes we need temp tables:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable SELECT ID, PRICE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ID = 1;
UPDATE PRODUCTS SET `PRICE` = (select tmptable.`PRICE` from tmptable where tmptable.ID = 1);
```

BUT! @forpas solution's is really good and works without creating a temp table.

enjoy.

NEW question: is the temp table removed automatically? Leave me a comment.
Cheers

Comment: What do you mean *none of them had the precise answer*? Did you try my answer? Also using a temp table for such a simple case is absurd.

Comment: Sorry @forpas, I answered before you, I didn't see yours before, I meant by other answers in Stackoverflow or in the internet in general.

Comment: @forpas Actually yours is pretty good and I up-voted and left you some comments, thanks a lot! Just one question, what is the negative impact of a temp table? Does it stay for long?

Comment: MySQL removes the temporary table automatically when the session ends or the connection is terminated. Of course, you can use the  DROP TABLE statement to remove a temporary table explicitly when you no longer need it

Comment: That said, i agree with forpas, for this scenario is too much overkill

Answer (score 0):

If this is a SQL script, i suggest you to break it into 2 queries using a variable:

```
select @var := PRICE from PRODUCTS where ID = 1;
UPDATE PRODUCTS SET PRICE = @var;
```

Variables are much more easier than temporary table in my opinion.

I've not fully tested, but the syntax should be that